# Bash read time run faster than what specified

Tags: bash

This is the bash code

```sh
read -t 10 -p "Video path ==>" VIDEO_SOURCE
    [ "$VIDEO_SOURCE" = q ]
if [ "$VIDEO_SOURCE" = "$NONE" ]; then
 ./run.sh
```

Basically what i wanted it to do is to run ./run.sh after 10 seconds if i didn't give it any input, the problem is that is runs the ./run.sh in less then 10 seconds.

Edit:

This is the full script

```sh
#! /bin/bash

VBR="1500k"
FPS="24"
QUAL="superfast"

RTMP_URL="rtmp://live.live"
KEY="xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"
VIDEO_SOURCE="video.mp4"

while :; do

 ffmpeg \
        -re -f lavfi -i "movie=filename=$VIDEO_SOURCE:loop=0, setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB)" \
        -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR \
        -f flv "$RTMP_URL/$KEY"

    read -t 10 -p "Video path ==>" VIDEO_SOURCE
    [ "$VIDEO_SOURCE" = q ]
if [ -z "$VIDEO_SOURCE"]; then
 ./run.sh
 fi
done
```

What i wanted it to do is to wait 10 seconds after a crash or after i press `q` , after 10 seconds either is going to run the new input if specified it, if the input is invalid or empty (in case i was too slow typing the input or in case of a crash) i wanted it to run `./run.sh`, i'm running this script in `tmux` just to keep it running and if i want to update the input i just go back to the `tmux` session and press `q` and give it the new input.

Comment: That should wait up to 10 seconds for input (although I'm not sure the `[ ]` tests are doing what you want). Are you sure this is running in bash, not some other shell? Do you get any sort of error message from it?

Comment: No i don't get any error,  i'm kind of new to dealing with scripts, sometimes i get confused, i think the ```[  ]```are working because when there is no input the ./run.sh starts, i actually felt that the syntax is not correct, but since the script is "working" i thought everything is okay, can you write the correct syntax so that i understand better

Comment: The syntax is technically valid, but the `[ "$VIDEO_SOURCE" = q ]` test doesn't do anything (more accurately, it tests to see if the `VIDEO_SOURCE` variable is set to "q", but it doesn't do anything with the result), and the [ "$VIDEO_SOURCE" = "$NONE" ] test compares the `VIDEO_SOURCE` variable with another variable named `NONE` (is that supposed to be testing whether `VIDEO_SOURCE` is empty? If so, use `[ -z "$VIDEO_SOURCE" ]`). As for the timeout, try putting just the `read ...` line in a script all by itself and see if it waits 10 seconds. If doesn't pause, how are you running it?

Comment: What i did is set NONE to ```NONE="" ```  so that  when there is no input it runs ```./run.sh ``` , what i'm trying to do is making a loop, if the script crashes and i'm not there it just runs again the ```./run.sh ``` that is the script itself repeating himself, what ```[ "$VIDEO_SOURCE" = q ] ``` is doing is when i press ```q ``` i can specify the video source myself, if i didn't within 10 seconds it just runs ```./run.sh ``` which is the script itself, i know i'm trying  is the complicated way to do it, but my knowledge is limited, i'm still learning.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. `read -t 10` waits 10s for me in bash 4.4 and [4.3](https://onlinegdb.com/Tx4g4KR_8B). Did you start your script with redirected input (e.g. `cmd | myscript.sh` or `myscript.sh < file`)?

Comment: I start my script with just ```./myscript.sh``` i read somewhere about the exact problem that i have, i remember a while ago someone wrote about ```read``` stops being accurate with scripts that are running for hours which is my case right now, there was a solution to that, i searched for that solution i couldn't find it, i remember someone said that every time ```read -t (time)``` runs within the same script the (time) losses millisecond(s), i hope you understand what i mean

Comment: @TheRedM When you say it runs in "less than 10 seconds", are we talking about it running in 9.99 seconds, or 5 seconds, or immediately, or what? Also, what shebang (first line, starting with `#!`) are you using in the script?

Comment: Actually in the first minutes after i ran the script i press ```q``` it waits 10 seconds for my input with no problem, but after i come back to it let's say after 12 hours it doesn't wait, the script is running now, it was running about 4 hours i pressed ```q``` it waited about 7 seconds,  I'm using ```#! /bin/bash```

Comment: @TheRedM Now I'm even more confused. What's running for 12 hours? Is the script running this `read` step periodically in a loop or something? There appears to be more involved here than you've told us about, and it'll be really hard to tell what's going on without a more complete picture. On the other hand, we don't really want to deal with an entire complex script. Please create a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the problem -- that is, take your script and trim everything that isn't needed to show the problem, and post that.

Comment: Sorry for making this thread going longer than necessary and thanks for your help, i updated the post with more details

Comment: Why not just take the path as an argument to the script?

Comment: @KamilCuk can you simplify what do you mean, my bash knowledge is like 1%

Comment: Thank you for the additional information, but I still cannot reproduce your problem. I ran bash 4.3.48 `while true; do echo "$SECONDS"; read -t 10 var; done > out` for 4 hours without input; everything worked fine. Then I once entered `q`, pressed enter after `6` seconds, and let it run without any further input again; everything worked fine. The script now ran for 23h and I still haven't seen `read -t` skipping the timeout. `awk 'NR>1 {print $1-last} {last=$1}' out | sort | uniq -c` showed me that `read -t` waited 8366×10s, 43×11s, 1×9s, and 1×6s (because I entered something once).

Comment: Thank you everyone, the problem is solved,  I ran the script for about 24 hours, after i came back i pressed ```q``` it waited 10 seconds, i think what solved the problem is using ```[ -z "$VIDEO_SOURCE" ``` to check for the ```VIDEO_SOURCE``` variable as @Gordon-Davisson suggested, i'm very sorry again for keeping this thread going longer than necessary and thanks to everyone who got involved in solving my "newbie" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your problem. Nevertheless, if there really was such a strange problem, you could try to work around it using the following hack:

```
read var < <(timeout --foreground 10 head -n1)
```

This should behave somewhat like `read -t 10` but relies on the external program `timeout` instead of `read`'s built-in timeout functionality.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved by adding -z ```[ -z "$VIDEO_SOURCE" ]``` to check for the ```VIDEO_SOURCE```` variable, i needed more than 24 hours to make sure everything is fine, your answer seems to be a good workaround for this problem and other problems that involves inaccurate time, i will mark it as the answer.